# In Matlab, error using length(x), gives subscript indicies error

Tags: matlab, vector, size, spline

Im extracting time-dependent data from a .dat file, and using the spline function, matching the values to an existing time-vector in use. For some reason the length function is failing to read the length of the vector.

I can recreate the error with this blurb:

```
x = linspace(1,98,76)';
y = 20.*x-5.*x.^2;
t = linspace(0,100,1000)';
yy = spline(x,y,t);
length(yy)
```

It returns

> ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

It shows in my workspace that yy is 1000x1 double, and max(size(yy)) works fine. Any idea on what creates this error?

Comment: I do not get an error running that code on R2012b on Linux Mint. Try adding `clear` to the top of your blurb, and if it starts working correctly, then you will know that Praetorian's idea is correct.

Comment: I also do not get an error in R2010b on ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 8):

You probably have a variable named `length` in your workspace. Use the [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) command to see if this is the case.

```
whos length
```

This will print out the size and type of the variable `length` if it exists.